# Crystallization of Glycerin

Tags: organic-chemistry, phase

Is it possible to crystallize vegetable glycerin?

I saw a myth about it online and was wondering if it is possible.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to Chemistry SE. I suggest you put in a link to the page you read this myth on to help us answer your question better.

Comment: I guess this link explains a lot : http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961351-nine-hours-nine-persons-nine-doors/57582553

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, for example by adding a seed crystal under the right conditions.

See the reference for further information: http://www.google.com/patents/US2233606